# How much data does Pokemon Go use?

Tags: pokemon-go

I'm playing Pokemon Go but I'm concerned about how much data it uses. How much data does it use on average?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**UPDATE**

I've been monitoring the data used of Pokemon Go to further test how much data is actually being used. Between the release and as today, Pokemon Go has accumulated 65.43MB worth of data. Roughly 90% of that was used while using 3G rather than connected to Wi-Fi. Most of the time I was in a sedentary environment hoping Pokemon would come my way, but I was also out-and-about a good bit of the time.

[image]

---

I have reviewed a few different sources and they all say Pokemon Go will use a good amount of data.

[10 Best Ways to Reduce Data Usage](http://www.pokemongodb.net/2016/04/10-best-ways-to-reduce-data-usage.html)

> Pokemon Go will require a Strong Wi-Fi or network connection to play. Unless you have an Unlimited Data Plan or expect to play only in areas where Wi-Fi is available, you will need a Data Plan to play Pokemon Go. Your phone will also need to meet certain requirements.
>
> Pokemon Go can average anywhere from 2MB - 8MB+ of data per hour, dependent on a variety of gameplay factors (Eg. Battling, Capturing, Walking).
>
> Based on this information, if half of a 2GB data plan is allocated to playing Pokemon Go, users can reasonably expect to play four to six hours per day without an any issue. If Pokemon Go is played for more than six hours per day, an upgraded data plan may be needed

**Best Ways to Reduce Data Usage**

> The main purpose of this article is to enable users to enjoy Pokemon Go without having to constantly monitor Data usage. Every Pokemon Go Trainer should be able to travel the world freely without fear of exceeding data limits. Fortunately, there are many ways Data usage can be reduced or limited.
>
> 1. Download Applications and Updates only Using Wi-Fi
> 2. Play Only in Areas where Wi-Fi is Available
> 3. Set a Data Limit
> 4. Browse Mobile Versions of Sites
> 5. Chrome Data Saver
> 6. Limit/Remove High Data Consuming Apps
> 7. Restrict Background Data
> 8. Avoid Streaming Videos, Music, Media
> 9. Avoid Downloading of Media w/ Data
> 10. Turn off Mobile Data

Other Sources

[Yes, Pokemon GO Uses a Lot of Data and Battery](http://comicbook.com/2016/07/07/yes-pokemon-go-uses-a-lot-of-data-and-battery-/)

[Your biggest Pokémon Go questions, answered](http://www.polygon.com/2016/7/6/12105992/pokemon-go-guide-faq-ios-android)

[Spending a day on 'Pokémon Go' is not good for your phone's battery life](http://mashable.com/2016/07/07/pokemon-go-battery-life/#DFbSJlJlUkql)

Comment: Doesn't seem that bad, thanks for the info.

Comment: To the layman, that really isn't much. I am on a bad data plan, in a country where data is considered expensive, and still would not have any problems with that kind of usage. By comparison, playing Pokemon Go for an hour is the equivalent of watching 1 or 2 YouTube videos.

Comment: I can second that. Have about 55 MB since I started playing about 1.5 weeks ago.

Answer (score 1):

It has used exactly 120 MB of data in roughly 10 hours of non-wifi play time. And I was walking at a pretty fast pace for the large majority of that time.

**So, in short, expect 10-15 MB per hour**. Which, in my opinion, is really not a lot considering the nature of the game.

I have used google maps's feature of pre-downloading a section of the world map for offline usage (in my case, I downloaded my whole city). No idea if Pokemon GO makes use of this

Answer (score 0):

I used about 200 MB of data on a 75 minute walk playing the game.

Comment: Highly unrealistic..

Comment: @Insane not really. If they walked too fast, they might have downloaded too much map data, resulting in 200mb, however I'd really like to see a screenshot like other answer shows too - other apps might have used data too.

Comment: @ardaozkal No. I drive with the game open (no power saver) so imagine the map data I'm downloading -- and I've not passed 100mb _total_ usage much less 65 minutes _walking_.

Comment: @Insane well, I guess that clarifies it. Dear user156639, please edit in a screenshot :)

Comment: @ardaozkal That would be nice. I confirmed and I'm at 105mb total usage, which if you want, I _can_ upload a screenshot.